# Skip an identity directly on query

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity

I have this situation:

**TABLE 1**

- ID,
- Other columns

**TABLE 2**

- ID,
- Other columns

What I want to achieve is that upon an insert query on one of the tables, if identity already exists in the other then skip it and pick a new one.

Why? Because these tables are basically related, but without any database relationships. When an user wants to call an object belonging to the other table, he should be able to by only knowing the ID of one of the tables.
In my case, I have **income/financial accounts** associated with **registries**, and they MUST have the **same ID**.

**Currently adopted solution (nasty one)**

A transaction. Commit if the generated id doesn't exist in the other table, abort if exists, and thanks to a while loop (this is the part I don't like) transactions will keep getting instantiated until the condition is met.

Any other clean solutions out there?

Comment: The crux of your problem starts right here "without any database relationships". If you fix your architecture you don't have to jump through all these hoops.

Comment: Put even ids in one table and odd ids in the other.  That would seem to fix your problem.

Comment: I agree, although nothing comes in my mind at the moment. Read in the comments below and see what my exact need is

Comment: Or, use a tally table of values that aren't in your base tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identities are not good for this case. The solution: you need to use a single sequence for inserting in both tables. Plain and simple.

This is the clean solution. All others are just (ugly) workarounds.

Comment: Yeah, that's plain and simple. But the fact is that this "relationship" doesn't always have to happen, it's just about having the identity slots free when the end-user wants to create an object related to the other. In my situation, i have economic/financial accounts related to registries. So I let you guess the rest. IDs must be equal, but not necessarily a registry must have an account

Comment: @k1dev so you can still use a central sequence. When you need to insert a new row, you grab the next number off the stack, if there's a relationship you insert it into both tables, if there isn't, you only insert it into one. Again, pretty clean and simple. `IDENTITY` is *not* the feature you're looking for.

Comment: The need of a  "relationship" is remote. You never know when it can happen, it may or may not be there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange request, but you can increment the identity values so one is even and the other odd.  Then there will never be any overlaps between the two tables:

```
create table table1 (
    table1_id int identity(1, 2) primary key,
    . . . 
);

create table table2 (
    table2_id int identity(2, 2) primary key,
    . . .
);
```

This would appear to fulfill your requirement in the most efficient way I can think of.